# Why does it take so long to get editing information when asking a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, performance, focus

I've started asking this question, and the editing toolbar has still not displayed.  I'm timing it, and wondering how long it will take for the toolbar to display.  Is this just an issue for me, or for others?  I do not have any responses in for my account, and yet it took just over a minute for the related questions and toolbar to come up, as I typed.  And, then, when it did come up, it took the focus from this edit box to the title, while I was typing.  That's especially annoying.

I know it takes awhile if I have responses for my account, and I have to stop the browser (IE 7) in order to do an upvote.  But this seems like the slowness is related to the searching for related questions.

Comment: You have the same issues with FireFox/Opera/Chrome? You cleared your cache? Bought more RAM? New computer?

Comment: It's a feedback response via a neural web interface that SO sites use.  The more you feel the need to edit, the longer it takes for the edit box to come up.

Comment: It's a work computer, and we're limited in the software we're allowed to use, including browsers.  However, I'll try clearing the cache and see if that helps.  New computer or upgrade would be nice, but it won't happen.

Comment: I haven't seen that issue, but I find it absolutely painful to leave a comment on a page with lots of content, getting in about 1 character per 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like basic network connectivity problems.

As others have mentioned, try in a different browser to see if that helps as well.

I'm not aware of any systemic network problems on our end.

Comment: Yeah, at home it's plenty fast.  So it's something with my work computer.  I tried clearing the cache and it didn't make any difference.  I guess something is interfering, and if I'm lucky, I'll be able to figure it out.  I don't have a lot of control over the computer, however.

Answer (score 0):

This should no longer be an issue since we have real-time updates to questions and answers (provided your browser supports web sockets).

You'll see an edit notification the instant an edit has been posted to either, with a click option to update to the current text (without reloading the page).